# Android: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, android-graphview

So my App reads Data from a JSON File stores them in a Class called "DataWarehouse" and notifies all Observes to get the new Data.

One of the Observers is a Plotter that uses graphView lib. to draw Lines. As the sorting and calculating of the new Coordinates take to much time I do this in a Thread "CalcCoordinatesThread". 
But I'm getting an error message and the Thread is not even running.

It's my first time using Threads in Android and I don't really know what I'm doing wrong, I worked on that for almost a day now. Help is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Stack-Trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.tobias.infinity_racing_driverless, PID: 13911
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:724)
    at com.example.tobias.infinity_racing_driverless.PlotterRunnable.start(PlotterRunnable.kt:49)
    at com.example.tobias.infinity_racing_driverless.PlotterRunnable.update(PlotterRunnable.kt:37)
    at com.example.tobias.infinity_racing_driverless.DataWarehouse.notifyObservers(DataWarehouse.kt:34)
    at com.example.tobias.infinity_racing_driverless.DataWarehouse.setValues(DataWarehouse.kt:54)
    at com.example.tobias.infinity_racing_driverless.JsonParser.onPostExecute(JsonParser.kt:58)
    at com.example.tobias.infinity_racing_driverless.JsonParser.onPostExecute(JsonParser.kt:12)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

CalcCoordinatesThread:

```
class CalcCoordinatesThread(private var uiHandler: MainScreen.UiHandler) : HandlerThread("CalcCoordinatesThread") {

private var handler: Handler? = null

//calc blue Cones
private fun calcBlueLines(blueCones: ArrayList<Cone>): LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> {

    var blueLines = LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>()
    var blueConeArrayList = ArrayList<DataPoint>()
    var blueIterator = 0

    val sortedBlueCones = blueCones.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.xCoordinate })) as MutableList<Cone>


    for (i in sortedBlueCones) {

        var x: Double = sortedBlueCones.get(blueIterator).xCoordinate
        var y: Double = sortedBlueCones.get(blueIterator).yCoordinate

        var dataPoint = DataPoint(x, y)
        blueConeArrayList.add(dataPoint)
        val blueConeArray = arrayOfNulls<DataPoint>(blueConeArrayList.size)
        blueConeArrayList.toArray(blueConeArray)

        blueLines.resetData(blueConeArray)

        blueIterator++
    }
    blueConeArrayList.clear()

    return blueLines
}

//calc yellow Cones
private fun calcYellowLines(yellowCones: ArrayList<Cone>): LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> {

    var yellowLines = LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>()
    var yellowConeArrayList = ArrayList<DataPoint>()
    var yellowIterator = 0

    val sortedYellowCones = yellowCones.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.xCoordinate })) as MutableList<Cone>


    for (i in sortedYellowCones) {
        var x: Double = sortedYellowCones.get(yellowIterator).xCoordinate
        var y: Double = sortedYellowCones.get(yellowIterator).yCoordinate

        var dataPoint = DataPoint(x, y)
        yellowConeArrayList.add(dataPoint)
        val yellowConeArray = arrayOfNulls<DataPoint>(yellowConeArrayList.size)
        yellowConeArrayList.toArray(yellowConeArray)

        yellowLines.resetData(yellowConeArray)

        yellowIterator++
    }

    yellowConeArrayList.clear()
    return yellowLines
}

//Handler gets and sends new Messages
private fun getHandler(looper: Looper): Handler {
    return object : Handler(looper) {
        override fun handleMessage(msg: Message?) {
            super.handleMessage(msg)

            //get Message with coordinates of Cones
            val coordinates = msg?.obj as Array<ArrayList<Cone>>

            //calc Lines
            var blueLines = calcBlueLines(coordinates[0])
            var yellowLines = calcYellowLines(coordinates[1])

            //Send Message of new LineSeries
            val lineMessage = Message()
            lineMessage.obj = arrayOf<LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>>(blueLines, yellowLines)
            uiHandler.sendMessage(lineMessage)

        }
    }
}

//Handler gets Message with new coordinates of Cones
fun sendCoordinates(coordinates: Array<ArrayList<Cone>>) {
    val message = Message()
    message.obj = coordinates
    handler?.sendMessage(message)
}

//start looper
override fun onLooperPrepared() {
    super.onLooperPrepared()
    handler = getHandler(looper)
}
```

}

Plotter:

```
class PlotterRunnable(private var calcCoordinatesThread: CalcCoordinatesThread) : Observer, Runnable {

private var thread: Thread = Thread(this)

var blueLines = LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>()
var yellowLines = LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>()

init {
    //First Values so resetData works
    yellowLines.appendData((DataPoint(0.toDouble(), 0.toDouble())), true, 1000)
    blueLines.appendData((DataPoint(0.toDouble(), 0.toDouble())), true, 1000)

    register()
}

//Register at Data Warehouse
override fun register() {
    DataWarehouse.registerObserver(this)
}

//Get new Cones from Data Warehouse and sort them by X Values
override fun update() {

    if(!thread.isAlive)
    {
        start()
        run()
    }
}

override fun run() {

    val coordinateArray = arrayOf<ArrayList<Cone>>(DataWarehouse.blueConesList, DataWarehouse.yellowConesList)
    calcCoordinatesThread.sendCoordinates(coordinateArray)
}

fun start(){
    thread.start()
}
```

}

Main:

```
class MainScreen : AppCompatActivity() {

//define variables
private lateinit var start: Button
private lateinit var graphView: GraphView
private lateinit var engineTempText: TextView
private lateinit var speedText: TextView

private val timer = Timer("schedule", true)
private var started = false

private lateinit var plotter: PlotterRunnable
private lateinit var uiHandler: UiHandler
private lateinit var calcCoordinatesThread: CalcCoordinatesThread
private lateinit var engineTempObserver: EngineTempObserver
private lateinit var speedObserver: SpeedObserver

//find GUI fields/buttons
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen)

    start = findViewById(R.id.startButton)
    graphView = findViewById(R.id.graphView)
    engineTempText = findViewById(R.id.engineTempText)
    speedText = findViewById(R.id.speedText)

    //Register Observers at DataWarehouse
    engineTempObserver = EngineTempObserver(engineTempText)
    speedObserver = SpeedObserver(speedText)

    uiHandler = UiHandler(graphView)

    //Wait till Button is pressed to start
    start.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

        //end
        if (started) {
            timer.cancel()
            timer.purge()
            started = false
        }

        //start
        else {
            started = true
            start()
        }
    })
}

//start monitoring
private fun start() {

    calcCoordinatesThread = CalcCoordinatesThread(uiHandler)
    plotter = PlotterRunnable(calcCoordinatesThread)

    val timer = Timer("schedule", true)
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(500, 500) {

        //Start
        if (started) {
            val jsonParser = JsonParser()
            jsonParser.execute()
        }

    }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    calcCoordinatesThread.quit()

}

class UiHandler(var graphView: GraphView) : Handler() {

    override fun handleMessage(msg: Message?) {
        super.handleMessage(msg)
        var lines = msg?.obj as Array<LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>>

        var blueLine = lines[0]
        var yellowLine = lines[1]

        graphView.addSeries(blueLine)
        graphView.addSeries(yellowLine)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is it possible you are trying to start a thread after it has completed? According to Thread javadocs: "It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution."  And the result of trying to start a thread that was already started is an IllegalThreadStateException, just as you are seeing. You may need to implement some kind of check to make sure you never call start() more than once.

Comment: @Greg Moens I check if the Thread already runs when I try to start it.

Comment: @Solomon Slow PlotterRunnable.update() is the Function that gets called when new Data is available. I implemented the whole thing as an Observer Pattern. 
Yes start() and run() are kinda stupid its old Code before I tried to Implement it as a Thread. I will make it one Function. It's a School Project so I'm still learning and not a Professional Programmer :)